# Does the YTM for a zero coupon treasury equal the treasury yield curve value for it's maturity?

Tags: yield-curve, yield

The title is my question.  I think the answer is yes, but I am unsure about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, generally this will not be the case. The yields of the on-the-run treasuries for specific tenors are collected and a cubic spline is fit to these points. Thus, the yields will only match for the on-the-run 1m, 3m, 6m, 12m, 2y, 3y, 5y, 7y, 10y, and 30y treasuries.

For details please see the page on [Treasury Yield Curve Methodology](https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/Pages/yieldmethod.aspx).

> The Treasury's yield curve is derived using a quasi-cubic hermite
>   spline function. Our inputs are the Close of Business (COB) bid yields
>   for the on-the-run securities. Because the on-the-run securities
>   typically trade close to par, those securities are designated as the
>   knot points in the quasi-cubic hermite spline algorithm and the
>   resulting yield curve is considered a par curve.
>
> ...
>
> More specifically, the current inputs are the most recently auctioned
>   4-, 13-, 26-, and 52-week bills, plus the most recently auctioned 2-,
>   3-, 5-, 7-, and 10-year notes and the most recently auctioned 30-year
>   bond, plus the composite rate in the 20-year maturity range. The
>   quotes for these securities are obtained at or near the 3:30 PM close
>   each trading day. The inputs for the four bills are their bond
>   equivalent yields.

Comment: If I understand what you said correctly, a hypothetical on-the-run zero coupon treasury would have a yield to maturity that matched the yield curve for it's maturity.  But generally, there wouldn't be a treasury for every maturity on the curve?

Comment: Yes and yes. I will update my answer to provide more details.

Comment: @GeorgeWolfe When the yield curve is upward sloping, the zero coupon yield will always be higher than the par yield of the same tenor; converse is true when the yield curve is downward sloping. Only time that zero coupon yield = par yield is when the yield curve is perfectly flat.